# codeigniter status code 400 bad request in index_post() method

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter

I keep on getting this error when performing post and put operations in my codeigniter restful api app.

here is the controller:

```
public function index_post(){
    if(!$this->input->post('city'))
    {
        $this->response(null,400);
    }
    $id=$this->cities_model->save($this->input->post('city'));
    if(!is_null($id))
    {
        $this->response(array('response'=> $id),200);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->response(array('error'=> 'sorry, data could not be saved...'),400);
    }
}
public function index_put(){
    if(!$this->input->post('city') || !$id)
    {
        $this->response(null,400);
    }
    $update=$this->cities_model->update($id,$this->input->post('city'));
    if(!is_null($update))
    {
        $this->response(array('response' => 'content updated successfully'),200);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->response(array('error'=> 'sorry, technical error occurred, please try again later...'), 400);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using `RESTController`? Post whole controller code here.

Comment: use `$this->post('city');` instead of `$this->input->post('city')` .

Comment: I am still getting the same error please.

Comment: You need to provide more info. Like how you calling api ? Post your whole controller code.

Comment: this is how am calling it: require APPPATH . '/libraries/REST_Controller.php';

class Cities extends REST_Controller{

    public function __construct() {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->load->model('cities_model');
    }

Comment: How did you test it ?

Comment: I am using postman

Comment: Put your Raw payload. Please update your question too with those details so other developer can also look into issue.

Comment: how is Put your Raw payload done please

Comment: Look for `code` link on postman it will show you Raw payload

Comment: I cant see the payload on the code link please:  POST /weatherapi/cities/index HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 54a46f3d-1555-2a12-9018-8080fdcaffb1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

Comment: you don't have `city` parameter in the parameter that's why it's showing `400`.

Comment: kindly explain to me where exactly it is supposed to be placed

Comment: select `form-data` and add `city` parameter with the appropriate value.

Comment: thanks buddy.it worked. however why is it saving only the first letter of the value

Answer (score 1):

There are few improvements and solution as per below.

```
public function index_post(){

    // Use validation library, instead of checking just for value.
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('city','City','trim|required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        // send back list of validation errors.
        $this->response($this->validation_errors(),REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    $id=$this->cities_model->save($this->post('city'));
    if(!is_null($id))
    {
        $this->response(array('response'=> $id),REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->response(array('error'=> 'sorry, data could not be saved...'),REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
public function index_put(){
    // for put you need to pass id as parameter 

    // Use validation library, instead of checking just for value.
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('id','ID','trim|required|integer');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('city','City','trim|required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        // send back list of validation errors.
        $this->response($this->validation_errors(),REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    $update=$this->cities_model->update($this->post('id'),$this->post('city'));
    if(!is_null($update))
    {
        $this->response(array('response' => 'content updated successfully'),REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->response(array('error'=> 'sorry, technical error occurred, please try again later...'), REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Now you need to pass `city` parameter from postman in `POST` body. it invoke `index_post` and you pass `city` and `id` parameter in `PUT` body,it invoke `index_put`.

Comment: thanks so much. but still only the first character of the value is saved with the status code 400.

Comment: for that, I need to look into your model file, also check your size of MySQL field.

Comment: there is also an error of  Illegal string offset 'id' in my model.

Answer (score 0):

```
 class Cities_model extends CI_Model
 {
  public function __construct()
  {
  parent::__construct();

  } 
 public function save($city)
 {
 $this->db->set($this->setCity($city))->insert('cities');
 if($this->db->affected_rows()>0)
 {
 return $this->db->insert_id;
 }
 return null;
 }
  public function update($id,$city)
{
$this->db->set($this->setCity($city))->where('id',$id)->update('cities');
if($this->db->affected_rows()===1)
{
 return true;
 }
 return false;
 }
  private function setCity($city)
  {
   return array('id'=>$city['id'],
         'name'=>$city['name']
         );
    }
    }
```

Comment: thats is my model file